# lua convert userdata to string

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to print out some userdata as a string, but the documentation for lua pretty weak to nonexistant. How do I convert a userdata variable to a string so that I can write it to a file?

Answer (score 4):

`tostring(userdata)`

Creator of that userdata must provide `__tostring` metamethod.

Comment: agreed. Or you'll get just `userdata: 0xdeadbeef` if that metamethod wasn't specified.